# create a virtual environment error when install tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

My system is windows and I have installed python 3.7 from Anaconda. I was following the instruction for install tensorflow 2.0
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

During the step of "2. Create a virtual environment (recommended)"
[image]

I copy/pasted the same code but received the error message "The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist"

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give full address of executable something like,

```
virtualenv env -p C:/Python36/python.exe
```

Comment: virtualenv --system-site-packages -p C:\Users\Gavin\Anaconda3\python.exe ./venv